# Extract data that satisfies the condition of the attribute

Tags: python, arcpy

> [image: This is the track point data, including the attribute such as the time, latitude, longitude, state, etc]
>
> According to the STATE property, the point will be extracted where the state is changed.Starting from the point numbered 0,the state is "重车",next is "空车",The STATE has changed,we can extract the point numbered 1.We continue to find the next point where the STATE changes,we can extract the point numbered 4.I want to find all the points where the STATE changes,can anyone help me ?

Comment: You need to add a code attempt or the question will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
import arcpy

name_of_feature_layer = "my_riks" #Change
valuefield = 'KKOD' #Change

data = 'sdsdff' #First row will Always be selected
oids = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(name_of_feature_layer,['OID@', valuefield]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[1] != data:
            oids.append(row[0])
        data = row[1]

sql = """{0} IN({1})""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(name_of_feature_layer, arcpy.Describe(name_of_feature_layer).OIDFieldName), ','.join([str(o) for o in oids]))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view=name_of_feature_layer, 
                                       where_clause=sql)
```

Then export the selected features to a new fc. I use the Python console with layer added to map. If you run outside ArcMap you need to use MakeFeatureLayer to create the layer and then select using this.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

My two cents (quick solution for QGIS). In `Select by Expression`:

```
attribute(get_feature_by_id( 'LayerName',$ID), 'FieldName') <> attribute(get_feature_by_id( 'LayerName',($ID-1)), 'FieldName')
```